# I want to parse this JSON with volley but I am not able to do it

Tags: android, json

I want to parse this JSON in Volley Library. I have set everything I want to parse name of the recipe and image. Problem is that I want three recipes to be parsed at same time but here it have same Object name Recipe and I don't know how to parse same object name for three different TextViews.

Here is the JSON format: [link](https://api.edamam.com/search?q=Chicken&app_id=5b3893fb&app_key=8918f0ef456a297902bed5ad81d0af81&from=0&to=3&calories=gte%20591,%20lte%20722&health=alcohol-free)

Here is the code I tried but it gave me one name not three different names:

```
try {

  JSONArray list = response.getJSONArray("hits");

  Log.v ("MISH", "List: " + list);

  for (int x = 0; x<list.length(); x++) {
    JSONObject obj = list.getJSONObject(x);
    JSONObject main = obj.getJSONObject("recipe");
    String label = main.getString("label");
    String image = main.getString("image");

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).into(recipeOne);

    Log.v("FISH", "NAME FATCH: " + label);
    recipeOneText.setText(label);

  }
```

Comment: You can check my answer . @Murtaza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

And use `optString` in your code:

```
try {
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(response)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "response is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
  }

  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
  JSONArray hits = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hits");
  // edited here ,add data in your code
  JSONObject jo1 = hits.getJSONObject(0);
  hits.put(0,jo1); // add jo1 JSONObject to the JSON array, the angle is 0
  hits.put(1,jo1); // add jo1 JSONObject to the JSON array, the angle is 1
  hits.put(2,jo1); // add jo1 JSONObject to the JSON array, the angle is 2

  for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jo = hits.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject recipe = jo.getJSONObject("recipe");
    String label = recipe.optString("label");
    String image = recipe.optString("image");

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).into(recipeOne);

    Log.v("FISH", "NAME FATCH: " + label);
    recipeOneText.setText(label);
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit**

```
// If your don't have to much data in your code , you can do like this .
JSONObject jo1 = hits.getJSONObject(0);
hits.put(0,jo1); // add jo1 JSONObject to the JSON array, the angle is 0
hits.put(1,jo1); // add jo1 JSONObject to the JSON array, the angle is 1
hits.put(2,jo1); // add jo1 JSONObject to the JSON array, the angle is 2
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i fetch 3 recipes with single parsing ? as this way i can get only one recipe at a time not 3.

Comment: You should add recipes JSONObject in your server . @Murtaza

Comment: I still dont get it :/ i am sorry i am doing this first time for parsing in JSON see here is the scenario There is one Array which have recipe no1, and for recipe no 2 and no 3 there is no Array they have just object. when ever i call recipe no 1 with Array it works. but when i try to parse Recipe no 2 and no 3 without an Array just with Object they don't appear at all.

Comment: JSONObject main2 = response.getJSONObject("recipe");
                        String label2 = main2.getString("label");
                        String image2 = main2.getString("image");

                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image2).into(recipeTwo);

                        Log.v("FISH", "NAME FATCH: " + label2);
                        recipeTwoText.setText(label2);

Comment: this is how i am trying to get recipe no 2 but no success :(

Comment: `JSONArray hits = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hits");
            int length = hits.length();`  length must be greater than 1 .And you will get more data .@Murtaza

Comment: Good luck to you . @Murtaza